# Could not resolve com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+

Tags: android, google-maps, android-gradle-plugin, google-directions-api

I'm on android studio 3. Can't seem to get seem to get this dependency resolved by my gradle. `implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'
It's important to note that I was forced to switch to the new format of using 'implementation' instead of 'compile' when I updated my gradle to version 4+.

[Here's a screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXHip.png)
Here's my app gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kenkarimi.dell.shift"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation files('libs/CircleImageView-master/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
    implementation 'com.firebase:geofire-android:2.3.1'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.jd-alexander:library:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Here's my project gradle gradle file:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
}
```

}

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Post your `project/build.gradle`

Comment: I've edited my original question with the entire gradle. Check out this line: implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'

Comment: No boy, do you not understood, I need that you do post the `project/build.gradle`, because you posted just the `app/build.gradle`

Comment: Fixed. Sorry mate, new to posting questions here

Comment: I am facing same problem, can you please share the steps used to resolve it

Comment: Hey, posted my answer below. I was never able to resolve the dependency, but I found a better way to do it. Hope it helps!

Comment: I removed "+", implemented only "com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5", sync project and  then everything works fine

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of using com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+ as a dependency, I just created a class within my project and pasted the contents of the said dependency.

So the class name is 'PolyUtil.class'. 
The only method within it is `decode(final String encodedPath)`

**How I use it.**
e.g. I call PolyUtil.decode(polylines[i]) to decode an encoded path string into a sequence of LatLngs

**Here's the Class**

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PolyUtil {
/**
 * Decodes an encoded path string into a sequence of LatLngs.
 */
public static List<LatLng> decode(final String encodedPath) {
    int len = encodedPath.length();

    // For speed we preallocate to an upper bound on the final length, then
    // truncate the array before returning.
    final List<LatLng> path = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    int index = 0;
    int lat = 0;
    int lng = 0;

    while (index < len) {
        int result = 1;
        int shift = 0;
        int b;
        do {
            b = encodedPath.charAt(index++) - 63 - 1;
            result += b << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x1f);
        lat += (result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1);

        result = 1;
        shift = 0;
        do {
            b = encodedPath.charAt(index++) - 63 - 1;
            result += b << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x1f);
        lng += (result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1);

        path.add(new LatLng(lat * 1e-5, lng * 1e-5));
    }

    return path;
    }
}
```

**Example of it's use in my code:**

```
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
    options.addAll(PolyUtil.decode(polylines[i])); //decode returns List<LatLng>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update :

Change the plug in into `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` you are currently using wrong plug in

Clear Android studio cache 
Menu -> File ->Invalidate Caches/Restart.

And clear gradle cache
On Windows:`%USER_HOME%\.gradle/caches/`

On Mac/Unix: `$HOME/.gradle/caches/`

Comment: Thanks! But the issue still persists.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing override of maven repository

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Still not resolved. I've edited the question with a screenshot of the error. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Delete your gradle folder and build folder and then rebuild it!